# Crear labels dinámicamente en función de contenido de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import tkinter as tk
lista = ['pasaje$25000$2018-01-25',
         'pension$200000$2018-01-25',
         'varios$40000$2018-01-25']
ventana = tk.Tk()

archivo = open("deudas.txt","r")

def callback(event):
    lab = event.widget
    text = lab["text"]
    print(text)

fr = tk.Frame(ventana)
fr.grid(row=0, column=0)

for elemento in lista:
    print(elemento)
    arreglo = elemento.split("$")
    for x, v in enumerate(arreglo):   
        text = tk.Label(fr, text=v)
        text.grid(row=x)
        text.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Con esto quiero crear *labels* dependiendo del tamaño de la lista, para así pesarle un evento que me retorne el texto del `label`. Para la lista del ejemplo, la idea es crear una matriz de 3 x 3 de la forma:

> <kbd>pasaje</kbd>   <kbd>25000</kbd>  
>   <kbd>2018-01-25</kbd>
>
> <kbd>pension</kbd> <kbd>200000</kbd>  <kbd>2018-01-25</kbd>
>
> <kbd>varios</kbd>    <kbd>40000</kbd>  
>   <kbd>2018-01-25</kbd>

El problema es que solo me itera sobre el último elemento de la lista. Agradeceria mucho la ayuda

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio robinson norambuena, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**

Comment: Hola Robinson, con la lista que muestras ¿cuantos labels se deben crear, con que texto y en que posiciones en el grid? En tus for anidados son incorrectos, estas volviendo a posicionar widgets en la misma casilla del grid (variable `x`).

Comment: la cantidad de labels va a depender de los valores de la lista

Comment: Ya..., pero ¿Para tu ejemplo serían 3 con el texto "pasaje", "pension" y "varios" o serían 9? Lo digo porque con tu for anidado y el uso de split estas creando 9 labels....

Comment: no me exprese bien, en efecto deberían ser 9 labels

Comment: Vale, ahora solo queda saber la posición en el grid. ¿Sería en una estructura de 3 x 3? Es decir, `pasaje`, `25000` y `2018-01-25` en la primera fila, `pension`, `200000` y `2018-01-25`, en la segunda, etc.

Comment: si, esa es la idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en el `for` anidado y a que solo especificas la fila (variable `x`) en la que va cada `Label`, lo que ocasiona que vuelves a posicionarlos en la misma celda del grid repetidamente.

La solución es especificar también la columna dónde cada widget ha de ser posicionado:

```
import tkinter as tk

lista = ['pasaje$25000$2018-01-25',
         'pension$200000$2018-01-25',
         'varios$40000$2018-01-25']

ventana = tk.Tk()
# archivo = open("deudas.txt", "r")

def callback(event):
    lab = event.widget
    text = lab["text"]
    print(text)

fr = tk.Frame(ventana)
fr.grid(row=0, column=0)

for x, row in enumerate(lista):
    for y, t in enumerate(row.split('$')):
        text = tk.Label(fr, text=t)
        text.grid(row=x, column=y)
        text.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

ventana.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas gracias, funcionó como queria